# Nokogiri - Get attributes?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Trying to use nokogiri to get values of attributes:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc  = Nokogiri::XML("<root attr=1></root>")
doc.root.attributes

#=> {}
```

Why isn't this working...?

Comment: Try `doc  = Nokogiri::XML("<root attr='1'></root>")`.  XML attribute values should be in quotes.

Comment: I see... That's somewhat a shame. I noticed just now that HTML seems to include interpretation of numbers without quotes. So I guess it's a difference between XML and HTML spec that initially confused me. Thanks!

Comment: XML is very strict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meditate on this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc  = Nokogiri::XML("<root attr=1></root>")
doc.errors # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: 1:12: FATAL: AttValue: " or ' expected>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: 1:12: FATAL: attributes construct error>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: 1:12: FATAL: Couldn't find end of Start Tag root line 1>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: 1:12: FATAL: Extra content at the end of the document>]
```

`doc.errors` is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

XML attribute values always need to be in quotes.

Since you've used double-quotes on the outside, you need to use single quotes inside:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc  = Nokogiri::XML("<root attr='1'></root>")
doc.root.attributes
```

Or you can do the opposite and have the double quotes on the inside with the singular quotes on the outside.

```
doc  = Nokogiri::XML('<root attr="1"></root>')
```